# Removing extra lines in psplotImp

Tags: pstricks

I am new to using pstricks and I am unsure of why I am getting extra lines.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-2.5)(2.5,2.5)
  \psaxes{<->}(0,0)(-1.5,-1.5)(1.5,1.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
  \psplotImp[linecolor=red,stepFactor=0.1,algebraic](-0.5,-1.3)(0.5,1.3){y*y*y-x-y}
 \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Garth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the manual of `pst-func`,

[image]

So you need to

- sufficiently enlarge the domain, named it exaggerated domain, in which the function to be plotted,
- crop the plotted graph using the original domain as the cropping box

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-2.5)(2.5,2.5)
  \psaxes{<->}(0,0)(-1.5,-1.5)(1.5,1.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
  \psclip{\psframe[linewidth=0,linestyle=none](-0.5,-1.3)(0.5,1.3)}
        \psplotImp[linecolor=red,stepFactor=0.1,algebraic](-0.55,-1.35)(0.55,1.35){y^3-x-y}
  \endpsclip
 \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Note

- PSTricks' algebraic parser can interpret `y^3` as `y*y*y` so you don't need to use the latter.
- When enlarging the domain, please realize that the larger domain used in `psplotImp`, the longer time to process it. Therefore, enlarge as minimal as  possible.

Comment: instead of `\psclip` simply use the `pspicture*` environment.

Comment: @Herbert: `\psclip` is more flexible in this case because I want to minimize the plotting area of `psplotImp` to reduce the processing time needed.

Answer (score 1):

The reason seems to be the fact you do not have a *closed* curve. The documentation explains the area  for the implicit plot must be greater than the area for the `pspicture*` environment (note the `*`, which will clip everything outside this area). Note it is simpler here to plot the curve as a parametric plots, since actually, $x=y:

```
\documentclass[pdf]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func}

\begin{document}

\psset{algebraic}
\begin{pspicture*}(-1.5,-1.5)(1.5,1.5)
    \psaxes{<->}(0,0)(-1.5,-1.5)(1.5,1.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psplotImp[linecolor=red,stepFactor=0.1](-2,-2)(2,2){y*y*y-x-y}
    \psparametricplot[linecolor=blue]{-1.3}{1.3}{t^3-t|t}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I agree with the parametric plot idea. The original function was y = (x+y)^(1/3) so I really was simply rearranging it to try and get it to work.